# jquery find the closest element

Tags: jquery, closest

Is there a jQuery function that combines the upward-looking `closest()` or `parents()` **and** the downward looking `children()` function?

For example:

```
<span id="container">
    <div class="a 1"></div>
    <div class="b 2"></div>
    <div class="c 3">
        <div class="d 4"></div>
        <div class="b 5"></div>
    </div>
<span>
```

`$(".c").something(".b");`should return the 'closest' `.b` element, or `.2`

Comment: I'm not aware of one. You could chain a few together however, to get this effect `$('.c').parent().children('.b');`

Comment: How would you differentiate between .b if .d was .b instead? you'd have two elements that are the same distance from each other, one in either direction.

Comment: what youre talking about is a matter of perspective.  I would consider the child element closer to .c as it resides with in it.

Comment: Do you have an order of operations? In other words, if the selectors were the "same distance" from `.c`, which would you want returned?

Comment: Clearly it doesn't exist because it would be difficult to decide what would be considered closest in the many different situations that can arise, leading to a method that is confusing/hard to understand.

Comment: Totally agree with all of you - thanks... i forgot to include that... So is it safe to say this doesn't exist and it's one or the other (or a combination)?

Comment: You can write your own function, depending on the order of operations. You need to decide if parent(), sibling(), or child() takes precedence (and in what order)

Answer (score 1):

I made sometime a little `closestDesc` plugin for this.

```
(function( $ ) {

  $.fn.closestDesc = function(selector) {

    var selection = [];

    var query = function () {
      this.children().each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(selector)) {
          selection.push(this);
        }
        else {
          query.call(this);
        }
      });
    };
    query.call(this);

    return this.pushStack(selection, "closestDesc", selector);
  };

})(jQuery);
```

This catches all *closest descendants*, matching the selector.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uGR2a/9/